# Why does Render Preview work but actually rendering crashes everything?

Tags: rendering, hardware

I have a somewhat complex test scene (not really that complex just a little demanding)

Here's the render preview:

[image: Screenshot of the Render Preview]

The render preview works fine but when I press render everything just crashes, so the question is what is the difference between the Render Preview and actually rendering the scene? 
Is it just because actually rendering a scene takes more computing power? if so are there a way to slow it down and use less computing power?

So far the only thing I got to render was the default cube

Also, a little more information. My setup for this is kinda weird, so there is no hardware acceleration for GPU compute, so I am using CPU for rendering. I'm also doing this just for fun so i don't expect and good performance from this setup

Comment: Welcome! You can share the blend using: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I'd also suggest to run your Blender from the system's console, start a render and see what gets written in the console when Blender crashes (and tell us what). It might give clues on what's happening. See this : https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/launch/windows.html

Comment: I had this issue when I was using the  2.81 version rendering eevee. Now with 2.82 it works fine.